# formatting the x-axis in Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, charts, stock

I'm trying to format my x-axis to show only dates. Here's my code:

```
start = datetime(2017, 1, 1)

end = datetime(2018, 3, 9)

stock = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'morningstar', start, end)

daily_close = stock[['Close']]

stock['Close'].plot(figsize=(12,8))


plt.xlabel('Date')

plt.xticks(rotation=30)






plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I may be using a different version of pandas or matplotlib, as I am not getting the same plot you are showing, however does this work for you? `stock.reset_index(level=0)['Close'].plot()`

Answer (score 0):

Place these lines before `plt.show()`

```
date_labels = [dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for dt in stock.index.get_level_values('Date')]
ticks, labels = plt.xticks()
new_labels = [date_labels[int(i)] for i in ticks if i < len(date_labels)]
new_ticks = ticks[0:len(new_labels)]
plt.xticks(new_ticks, new_labels)
```

The code converts the datetime from the index to a list of strings representing dates and overwrites the tick labels on the X axis with the corresponding dates.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not showing correct dates anymore

Comment: I want to remove AAPL and the 00:00:00 from the date

Comment: @ThanaaMakdsi I have updated the answer. It should display the correct dates now.